# How make layout 100% height

Tags: css, layout

How to make a simple layout 100% height (sidebar + content)?

See my source code: http://codepen.io/adilson/pen/kiHsd

Apparently the layout seems to be 100% of height but when resizing the browser and open the "menu item 10" it is clear that it is not.

Another problem is that the column "sidebar" border is not going to the bottom of the page.

**Edit:**
I would not want to have a scroll bar on the sidebar, what I'm trying to do is let the layout 100% height, and if the open menu automatically expand the layout.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/layout_blank_page.html

I just do not want the header and footer of this model, but the rest is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: not a clear question.

Comment: You open the code and preview in Codepen?

There you can clearly see what I related above ..

I want make the layout 100% height (sidebar + content)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your scroll bar is more then 100% height.

You can make them both the same height by using `containers`:

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxXFf/) example.

Comment: It´s a good ideia... maybe using containers and "display:table;" like this sample posted in other community: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DivFj

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overflow:auto to the #sidebar.

```
#sidebar{overflow:auto;}
```

This will automatically overflow the things.

Comment: Overflow creates a scroll bar in the sidebar.

Is there any other alternative? Maybe put all the content within a Wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this. One is to scroll the side navigation. The other is to limit the height of the sub-menu's and scroll them instead. For this, update your css as follows:

```
#sidebar ul li ul{max-height:230px;overflow:auto;}
```

You may want to experiment with the max height value of your nested list items until you get the desired look you are after.

To make your side bar scroll when the screen size is reduced add the following,

```
#sidebar {left: 0;bottom:0;top:0;width: 255px; background: #111; border-right:#000 solid 3px;overflow-y:auto;}
```

Adding top and bottom positions will ensure your sidebar stays in place and takes up 100% of the document height.

Hope this helps

Comment: lukeocom, I would like to avoid the scroll of sidebar.
I added an example of what would make in the initial message.

Comment: the difference between the designs is that you are trying to use a relative height of 100%. The example you provide of what you want uses a fixed height of 947px... you might like to add the following to your css. #container{height:800px;background-color:#555;width:100%;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: and then add a div with id of 'container' that surrounds the sidebar and content divs.